# Passing value to main class using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The purpose of my project is to recieve a sms message. So, the problem is, when i recieve a message i need to pass the message value to my main class. Here is my setup.

Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String mprovider;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //some activity is going on here.
}

public void reply(final String smsMessage) {
    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
    txtMessage.setText("message: "+smsMessage);
}
```

SmsReceiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "";

    if (myBundle != null)
    {
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");

        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                String format = myBundle.getString("format");
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
            }
            else {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage += " : ";
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            strMessage += "\n";
        }

        Log.e("SMS", strMessage);
        Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.reply(strMessage);
    }
}
}
```

As you can see. I declaring the main class and parsing the value to the method of the main class.

MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.reply(strMessage);

I don't think this is the right way to do it. it doesn't work anyway

Comment: You are right. You should not be making new activities like that.

Comment: Ok i am glad to know that i am wrong for sure. But whats the proper way to do this? :D

Comment: You have a receiver, so you need to broadcast a message to it. You could also look into using a library like EventBus

Comment: maybe i explained myself  wrong, but my problem is that i dont know how to pass a value from smsReciever class to my main class. Or is this just not possible.

Comment: It is possible, I just don't have experience with broadcast receivers. I do know that they act on some subscription service, though, in which the activity should subscribe to a message event and not directly be sent a  message

Answer (score 0):

You could make a singleton instance of your main activity. Or pass your main activity to the SmsReceiver instance.

Singleton would be kind of like this

```
 public class MainActivity.... {
     public static MainActivity instance;

     public void onCreate.... {
           instance = this
     }
}
```

Then you could reference to it like MainActivity.instance.
But it would be better to just pass your main activity instance to the sms receiver.